# Search question by combination of two or more tags

Tags: support, tags, search

I am trying to search question by two or more tags. Suppose I want to search questions that have tags like `android`, `android-layout`, and `edittext`.  Then I am unable to find that type of search criteria.

I tried to click on tag but it only shows question on that tag. If I want to add another tag in my search criteria then I am unable to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Just enter both tags in the search box, in the top-bar on the right. Searches are narrowed down by default the more criteria you enter.

For example [`[android] [android-layout] relativeLayout`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+%5Bandroid-layout%5D+relativeLayout) returns nearly 7000 results.

Note that on tag pages, the tag is already pre-filled in the search box; on the [android](/questions/tagged/android) page you'll notice that the search box comes with the text `[android]` already entered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below options:

- Use **`AND`** operator by just adding tags in search box; like `[android] [android-layout]`
- Use **`OR`** operator by adding `or` keyword between tags in search box; like `[android] or [android-layout]`
- Use **`NOT`** operator by adding `-` before a tag in search box; like `-[android]`

There are some rules for multiple uses of those keywords:

`[android] or [android-layout] [edittext]` is like `[android] or ([android-layout] [edittext])`

> Always search engine optimize tags of your search string and for those operators search engine apply `OR` over `AND`. And using `(` and `)` will make more sense

`[A] or [B] [C]` is not `( [A] or [B] ) [C]`

> **Note :**
>   Use a black space between `([` like `( [` for a correct search.